# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Problem

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I've been running into an EXC_BAD_ACCESS bug and have been racking my brain trying to figure out the solution.  I believe I know the issue but I can't narrow down the line that it's happening on and the debug log isn't helping me.  I've embedded the crash log below.  If anybody could help me figure out how to track things down I'd be extremely grateful!  I have turned on NSZombieEnabled but that is not giving me any additional information.

[image]

Comment: Valgrind is pretty much entirely a "tool of last resort".  There are much easier/obvious routes of investigation prior to that.  Symbolication, to start with, then expect the method/function that is crashing in the Holler codebase.

Comment: With that screenshot, one can only guess. Why don't you show on which line the error happens?

Comment: It looks like you can crash this app easily. Try to build&run from xcode, with the device attached, then make it crash, and then enter `bt` at the (gdb) prompt (Debugger console). You should get a backtrace telling you a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- text is better than a screenshot, but I think I can read that screen.
- the crash is in your code at 0x1000. You'll want to sybolicate that: [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)
- the frames in libobjc are most likely because you are passing a bogus pointer to objc_msgSend();  something that looks enough like a pointer that objc tries to poke at the garbage value is if it were an object.
- this isn't necessary an over-release problem;  could just be a trashed pointer / trashed memory.

---

You can probably disassemble the binary and figure out what symbols is that the address listed.  Or something pretty close.   `otool` is your friend.  `nm` might be, too.   But... proper symbolication is far superior.

Comment: The problem with that Symbolicating iPhone App Crash problem is that I'm already viewing this in the Organizer and it's not providing any information.   Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Seems like I need to upgrade to XCode 4.1 for symbolicating to work properly.  Now I'm upgrading to the latest OSX first :(

Answer (score 0):

while debugging set NZombieEnabled.It will helf you hunt down the probem.atleast why its crashing(on which object).